# function as method for all elements

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to create a function that will behave as method to all elements like JQuery methods. for exemple:

```
function myFunction(p1,p2){
    //things
}
element.myFunction(p1,p2);
```

I think that Object.prototype is not allowed .
Any idea ?? plz I am new to OOP in javascript. Thx

Comment: Do you want a function with an arbitrary amount of arguments? It's not very clear what you mean.

Comment: Adding a function to `Object.prototype` is "allowed" in the sense that it can be done and will work as expected, but doing so can lead to many problems that most (nearly all) JavaScript programmers treat this as verboten.  It *is*, however the way that you "add methods to _all_ (standard, not host) objects."  But are you looking to add a method to _certain_ objects or really to _all_ objects?  (There's not much reason IMHO to do the latter.)

Comment: No!! I will edit it if it's confusing

Comment: You can't actually do that for DOM elements in all browsers. I don't know about IE 8 and 9, but prior versions don't implement their JavaScript DOM API in such a way as to make it possible to do that.

Comment: But how jquery do it ?!!

Comment: jQuery doesn't add the methods to the DOM obejcts, it adds them to a `JQuery` object that references a collection of DOM objects.  Is this the kind of trick you are looking for?

Comment: What I want really to know is like jquery plugins style !!

Comment: @RayToal .. Oh I get it ^__^ !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ = function (element){
    return {
        myFunction: function (p1,p2){
            alert(element.id + " " + (p1 + p2));
            //do stuff with element and p1 and p2
        }
    }
}

$(document.getElementById("test")).myFunction(50,80)
```

This returns an object with that function in it. It uses lexical scoping to hold onto a reference to the element you gave it while still being able to pass in new parameters into `myFunction`

Here is a jsfiddle with this in action! http://jsfiddle.net/vnbQU/

Comment: Using wrappers this way is fine, but the downside is performance once they get big. jQuery suffers by having to make its big jQuery object every time, whereas plain function calls that are passed an element don't. It is the type of performance hit that prototype inheritance is designed to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

```
myFunction.call(element, p1, p2);
```

will call `myFunction(p1, p2)` with `this` bound to `element`, similar to if `myFunction` were in `element.prototype` and were called through `element.myFunction(p1, p2)`.

Comment: Yes that's what I am going to do .. I was jus looking if I can reduce arguments

Comment: That is really a waste of time as it just adds a layer of abstraction - why pass the element as *this* when you can pass it directly? It's less code to write and clearer for everyone.